# Creating a ".rc" file in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I'm trying to learn game programming. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express on Windows Vista. I want to know how to create a resource file (.rc). The microsoft website gives some fairly ambiguous instructions on creating one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxdy04be.aspx. If I go to my **Solution explorer**, right click and select **Add New Item**, the IDE does not give a .rc file as one of the options. It only gives me a .cpp, .h and windows form as options. I don't know what to do. I just can't figure out where i'm goofing up. I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot
Merry christmas!

Comment: Not supported.  It is just a plain text file, the format isn't very complicated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The Visual Studio Express 2010 does not have the ability to edit resource files. Take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx) it is the listing of which features each version of VS 2010 contain.

From above link. There is no resource editor in the Express Version. 
[image]

This [link](http://guy-lecky-thompson.suite101.com/vc-express-external-res-editor-a21264) discusses a way to add a resource editor to Visual Studio Express.
Also take a look at this [MSDN Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/254f1a84-d9e7-4a76-84f1-57584c6b00ed/) It has some tips and links to external editors.

Comment: Your answer doesn't already link to it, so I feel obligated to do so myself. I *highly* recommend [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) as a free (as in beer) resource editor for Win32. I don't know if it integrates with Visual Studio, but it's a fantastic application. Obviously you'll need the Platform SDK (which may or may not be included with VS Express nowadays), but you should download that anyway.

Comment: Adding link to [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/), which allowed me to create a rc file so I could include an ICO file in a VS 2010 Express project. +1