# Show a picture without borders and exit pure c

Tags: c, image, winapi, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp-sp3

How can this be done using Visual C++ 2008 Express?

Picture must be into executable.

I found i can modify background of borderless window using these lines:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcx;
/*fill up other wcx members*/
wcx.hbrBackground=CreatePatternBrush((HBITMAP) LoadImage(0,_T("background.bmp"),
                                 IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,
                                 LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_LOADFROMFILE));
```

or

```
WNDCLASSEX wcx;
/*fill up other wcx members*/
wcx.hbrBackground=CreatePatternBrush((HBITMAP) LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(0),
                                  MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_BACK_BMP),
                                 IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,
                                 LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

but i got a problem:

First example is used to get pictures from existing files.
Second one uses resorces. But I can not find an option how to add a resource (i think this is impossible for native projects)!
Is there any workaround?

Please help!

PS. Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0):

The express versions of Visual Studio do not include a resource editor. But you can use a 3rd party resource editor:

[Creating a ".rc" file in Visual Studio 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623078/creating-a-rc-file-in-visual-studio-2010-express)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a resource editor to compile resources into an executable image. The resource editor is merely a graphical editor for resource script files (.rc). Resource script files can be authored in any text editor. The file format is documented in the MSDN ([About Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599.aspx)).

To add a bitmap image resource you have to add a [`BITMAP` resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380680.aspx) definition statement to your resource script and create a unique resource ID in a header file (resource IDs for bitmaps must be in the [range from 0 to 32767](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5f4bses.aspx)):

resource.h:

```
#define IDB_BACK_BMP 1
```

MyApp.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDB_BACK_BMP BITMAP "background.bmp"
```

Assuming that your project is properly set up to invoke the [Resource Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042.aspx) for resource script files you can load the bitmap image from the executable image using:

```
HBITMAP hBM = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                 MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BACK_BMP),
                                 IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                 0, 0,
                                 LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

Note that you do not need to specify the `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag unless you want to send the image to a printer. For rendering to a display device context a device-dependent bitmap suffices.