# Working with resource files (.rc) in a Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface

I am new to C++ but I have programmed in other languages. I am trying to work on a project that someone else has created. The project uses resource files (.rc) to define window elements (buttons, checkboxes, etc). I can compile the project with no error; I can also use a text editor to look at the contents of the resource file. What I cannot do (don't know how to do) is to view and edit the resource file inside Visual Studio itself.

When I double click on it, "Resource View" opens up but it is blank. When I press F7 I can see the code, but I was wondering if there is a graphical way to visualize and edit the properties of that dialog.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? Some Express versions (2010 notably) don't come with the resource editor (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623078/creating-a-rc-file-in-visual-studio-2010-express).

Comment: I'm using 2010, but not the Express version. You can edit the .RC file as text, but that doesn't even come close to having a graphical view; it's just a script.

Comment: Something I cannot recommend (because I have not personally used it) but have at least heard good things about is the 3rd party editor from http://www.resedit.net

Answer (score 0):

The Resource View should show you a hierarchy tree, which is initially closed. Clicking on the little rectangle to the left of the tree should open successive levels of hierarchy, each with its own disclosure triangle. Soon you should see items such as "Dialogs", "Menus", etc.

If that does not work at all, it is indicative of some deeper problem with the project.

Comment: The project was upgraded form an earlier version of VS (I believe from VS 2010). I am using VS 2013, full version (not express). I do not see a tree as you described though.